# azure service bus timeouts

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I'm have 2 topics in my azure service bus.
topic1 = livetopic
topic2 = testtopic

live topic is timing out when I try to add any messages.
If I change my code to use testtopic it is fine.

I've disconnected all my publishers from livetopic still timing out.
I've deleted livetopic and re-added still timing out.

Any ideas on how to solve this.

I've tried using the service bus explorer sample app, it can see both topics, but it also times out on livetopic, but not testtopic.

Below is exception message:

> Server stack trace:  Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.DuplexCorrelationAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [1]:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c_*DisplayClass17.b*_a(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [2]:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.b__4(RequestAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [3]:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpTransactionalAsyncResult`1.b__37(TIteratorAsyncResult
>   thisPtr, IAsyncResult a)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [4]:
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.EndSendCommand(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndSend(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnSend(TrackingContext
>   trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(TrackingContext
>   trackingContext, IEnumerable`1 messages, TimeSpan timeout)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.Send(BrokeredMessage
>   message)
>
> at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.TopicClient.Send(BrokeredMessage
>   message)
>
> at myCompany.Azure.MessagePublisher.PublishMessage(String topic,
>   String destinationGroup, String messageCategory, String
>   destinationApp, String blobStorageDescription) in
>   c:\codetfs\MyProduct\MyCompany.Azure\MessagePublisher.cs:line 182

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any typo somewhere in your code?  If you create a new topic with another name (not live, nor test topic), is it working then?  If not, you might want to contact support

Comment: Yes I am sure, I even used the service bus explorer sample app, could see the topic, but when I tried sending messages there it timed out also. I think if you send to a non exsistant topic it gives a different error message (as I also tried that yesterday too).

Comment: Yes, that's right, you should get a 404 there.  Unless someone else has a better suggestion, I would try to contact support.

Comment: Can you pose the TimeoutException message you are seeing? Also, do you have any subscriptions for that topic to receive the message?